# How to eliminate empty rows from an HTML table formed from a google form girdbox question

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have been trying to build an easy to read order form for our EMS supply at the station. I have gotten to the point where it builds the table based on all answers, but I would like to eliminate some of the extra questions from showing up and would prefer there to only be the items that are needed in the rest of the table.

```
     function Mail(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var responses = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 3");
      var lastRow = responses.getLastRow();
      var values = responses.getRange("A"+(lastRow)+":AT"+(lastRow)).getValues();
      var headers = responses.getRange("A1:AT1").getValues();
      var message = composeMessage(headers,values);
      var messageHTML = composeHtmlMsg(headers,values);
      if (values =!'')
      Logger.log(messageHTML);
      MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'New Order', message,{'htmlBody':messageHTML});
    }

    function composeMessage(headers,values){
      var message = 'New Order :\n'
      for(var c=0;c<values[0].length;++c){
        message+='\n'+headers[0][c]+' : '+values[0][c]
      }
      return message;
    }

    function composeHtmlMsg(headers,values){
      var message = 'New Order :<br><br><table style="background- 
   color:white;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5> 
   <th>data</th><th>Values</th><tr>'
      for(var c=0;c<values[0].length;++c){
        message+='<tr><td>'+headers[0][c]+'</td><td>'+values[0][c]+'</td></tr>'
      }
     return message+'</table>';
    }

`
data    Values


Timestamp   Tue Nov 05 2019 21:58:30 GMT-0800 (PST)
Request for:    Station 1
Needs:  Medications
[Adenosine] 3
[Albuterol] 
[Amiodarone]    
[Aspirin]   
[Atropine MDV]  
[Atropine PLS]  
[Atrovent]  
[Benadryl]  
[Bicarb]    
[Calcium]   
[Charcoal]  
[D10]   
[D50]   
[Dopamine]  
[Epi 1:1,000]   2
[Epi 1:10,000]  
[Glucagon]  
[Glucose]   
[Lidocaine] 
[Narcan]    
[Nitro Paste]   
[Nitro Spray]   
[NS 100ml]  
[NS 250ml]  
[Saline for Inhilation] 
[Tylenol]   
[Ventolin]  
[Zofran ODT]    
[Zofran Vial]   
Further Needs?  Done
[IO Blue]   
[IO Pink]   
[IO Yellow] 
[Defib Pads]    
[Chest Seals]   
[4x4 QuickClot] 
[Rolled Gauze QuickClot]    
[OB Kits]   
[Stethoscope]   
[BP Cuff - Adult]   
[BP Cuff - Peds]    
[BP Cuff - Thigh]   
[Pressure Infuser]
```

Comment: Above I have one of my responses and I would like it to only have the lines:
Request for: Station 1-7
and then the items that have been selected: 2 Epi 1:1,000 and 3 Adenosine

I have tried to figure out how to eliminate rows that have no result, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Is there any chance you could post the plain HTML this generates in your answer to better assist us visualising / providing an answer?

Comment: Honestly I dont know how to do that... If you scroll down on my function above it shows the current values that fill the table.

Comment: Why not test for `values[0][c]` having a value, if yes, then insert the the html msg; if no, skip and go to next value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank cells are retrieved as a String, "". So the test is `=== ""` or conversely `!=""`

A re-worked `composeHtmlMsg()` might look like this;

---

```
function composeHtmlMsg(headers,values){
    var message = 'New Order :<br><br><table style="background-color:white;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5><th>data</th><th>Values</th><tr>'
    for(var c=0;c<values[0].length;++c){
        if (values[0][c] != ""){
            message+='<tr><td>'+headers[0][c]+'</td><td>'+values[0][c]+'</td></tr>'
        }
    }
  return message+'</table>';
}
```